# Receiving not defined in service after method execute

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I´m new in Angular and I want to create register action using Angular 5 with AspNet Web Api

When I clic Register in view it call Controller successfull, once controller finish it start executing service, but in service I always getting not defined on parameters mapping:

View:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && signup()" #f="ngForm" class="m-login__form m-

 form" action="">
<ng-template #alertSignup></ng-template>
<div class="form-group m-form__group">
  <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" placeholder="Empresa" name="empresa" [(ngModel)]="model.empresa" #empresa="ngModel">
</div>
<div class="form-group m-form__group">
  <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" [(ngModel)]="model.nombre" #nombre="ngModel">
</div>
<div class="form-group m-form__group">
  <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" placeholder="Apellido" name="apellido" [(ngModel)]="model.apellido" #apellido="ngModel">
</div>
<div class="form-group m-form__group">
  <input class="form-control m-input" type="text" placeholder="Correo Electronico" name="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email" #email="ngModel" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div class="form-group m-form__group">
  <input class="form-control m-input" type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel">
</div>
<div class="form-group m-form__group">
  <input class="form-control m-input m-login__form-input--last" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="rpassword" [(ngModel)]="model.rpassword" #rpassword="ngModel">
</div>
<div class="row form-group m-form__group m-login__form-sub">
  <div class="col m--align-left">
    <label class="m-checkbox m-checkbox--focus">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="agree" [(ngModel)]="model.agree" #agree="ngModel">
                       Estoy de acuerdo con los
                        <a href="#" class="m-link m-link--focus">
                          Términos y condiciones
                        </a>
                        .
                        <span></span>
                      </label>
    <span class="m-form__help"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="m-login__form-action">
  <button [disabled]="loading" [ngClass]="{'m-loader m-loader--right m-loader--light': loading}" id="m_login_signup_submit" class="btn btn-focus m-btn m-btn--pill m-btn--custom m-btn--air">
                      Registrarse
                    </button>
  <button [disabled]="loading" id="m_login_signup_cancel" class="btn btn-outline-focus  m-btn m-btn--pill m-btn--custom">
                      Cancelar
                    </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Service:

```
register(email: string, password: string, empresa: string, nombre: string, apellido: string) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:58607/api/account/Register', JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password, empresa: empresa, nombre: nombre, apellido: apellido }), { headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) })
      .map((response: Response) => {

        let user = response.json();
        if (user && user.token) {
          return user;
        }
      });
  }
```

Component:

```
signup() {
    this.loading = true;
    this._authService.register(this.model.email, this.model.password, this.model.empresa, this.model.nombre, this.model.apellido).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.showAlert('alertSignin');
        this._alertService.success(
          'Thank you. To complete your registration please check your email.',
          true);
        this.loading = false;
        LoginCustom.displaySignInForm();
        this.model = {};
      },
      error => {
        this.showAlert('alertSignup');
        this._alertService.error(error);
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
```

When I debbug it I get not defined in all parameters of service, like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Regards

**UPDATE**

In component I call model like:
 `user: User;`

then in service signup method call I do:

```
signup() {
    this.loading = true;
    this._authService.register(this.model).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.showAlert('alertSignin');
        this._alertService.success(
          'Thank you. To complete your registration please check your email.',
          true);
        this.loading = false;
        LoginCustom.displaySignInForm();
        this.model = {};
      },
      error => {
        this.showAlert('alertSignup');
        this._alertService.error(error);
        this.loading = false;
      });
  }
```

So I get this:

[image]

When it executed api controller and return success from api it returns message:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Note: I change service as:

```
register(user: User) {
    const body: User = {
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password,
      rpassword : user.rpassword,
      empresa: user.empresa,
      nombre: user.nombre,
      apellido: user.apellido,
      agree: user.agree
    }
    return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/api/account/Register', body)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        let user = response.json();
        if (user && user.token) {
        return user;
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: This is related to how Chrome debugger behaves and not anything else. It cannot reach a variable from parent function scope.

Comment: And the method signup() ??

Comment: I add signup method who is in component @erni

Comment: Have you try with vs code debugger ?

Comment: can you post the model.ts entity code?

Comment: its just an empty array like:  `model: any = {};` @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the register method to the following:

```
register(user: User) {
  const body: any = {
  'email': user.email,
  'password': user.password,
  'rpassword' : user.rpassword,
  'empresa': user.empresa,
  'nombre': user.nombre,
  'apellido': user.apellido,
  'agree': user.agree
}

let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/api/account/Register', JSON.stringify(body), options)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
    let user = response.json();
    if (user && user.token) {
    return user;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I do it, but when http.post called and executed it return status 200 but  when breakpoint reach line: `let user = response.json();` I get  `body is not defined` then if I continue I still getting SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: @David, that's because your service might not be returning anything. Check the service to verify if it is returning the user object.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a model "model.ts" with the following code:

```
export class Model {
    empresa: string;
    nombre: string;
    apellido: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    rpassword: string;
    agree: boolean;
}
```

and change the entity type in your component as below:

```
model:Model;
```

also do not forget to import the model in your component file:

```
import {Model} from './model';
```

Comment: I post an update in my question, can you take a look please?

Comment: @David, change the const to following
    const body: User = {
      'email': user.email,
      'password': user.password,
      'rpassword': user.rpassword,
      'empresa': user.empresa,
      'nombre': user.nombre,
      'apellido': user.apellido,
      'agree': user.agree
    }

Comment: @Davit, also you need to provide content-type for your request to let the http know that the content-type is "application/json".

Comment: I changed it as you say and added content type to header in service like:  `return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/api/account/Register', body, { headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) })` but still same error